# Parse multidimensional array by other array with specified keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i want to parse the main array using other array that contains the keys
For example, i have the following main array:

```
$test_array = [
       'something' => 'Ceva',
       'products' => [
           'item' => [
               [
                   'id' => '1',
                   'images' => [
                       [
                           'image' => 'image1.jpg'
                       ],
                       [
                           'image' => 'image2.jpg'
                       ]
                   ]
               ],
               [
                   'id' => '1',
                   'images' => [
                       [
                           'image' => 'image12.jpg'
                       ],
                       [
                           'image' => 'image22.jpg'
                       ]
                   ]
               ],
           ],
       ]
]
```

And this is the second array that contains the keys:

```
$settings = [
  'products_path' => 'products,item',
  'images_path' => 'products,item',
];
```

i need a way to get the specific path from array using settings array

```
example_function($test_array, $settings['products_path']);
```

should return:

```
    [
    'id' => '1',
    'images' => [
        [
            'image' => 'image1.jpg'
        ],
        [
            'image' => 'image2.jpg'
        ]
    ]
],
[
    'id' => '1',
    'images' => [
        [
            'image' => 'image12.jpg'
        ],
        [
            'image' => 'image22.jpg'
        ]
    ]
],
```

UPDATE

I have done this using this function:

```
public function getPath($array, $columns, $return = []) {
        if(!empty($columns)) {
            foreach ($columns as $column_key => $column) {

                if(isset($array[$column])) {
                    unset($columns[$column_key]);
                    $return = $this->getPath($array[$column], $columns);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $return = $array;
        }

        return $return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the example is as simple as it looks, you can just separate the values inside the $settings key and use them as your array indexes.

```
function example_function($test_array, $settings_key_value ) {

    // Separate the two $settings values from the 'product_path' key at the comma, using the first as your first index inside $test array, and second word as second index.
    $settings_value = explode(',', $settings_key_value);
    $new = $test_array[$settings_value[0]][$settings_value['1']];

}
```

Just call the function as in your example:

```
example_function($test_array, $settings['products_path']);
```

Also, probably 11,000 alternatives to get to your answer.  All the tools are sitting right there for 'ya, and if the $settings array can be altered a bit you wouldn't even need the explode() function to get there.

EDIT:  Since you may have different amounts of values in each key:

```
function example_function($test_array, $settings_key_value ) {

    $settings_values = explode(',', $settings_key_value);
    foreach ($settings_values as $settings_value ) {
        $output = $test_array[$settings_value];
        if ( is_array( $output )) {
            $test_array = $output;
        }
        break;
    }

    return $test_array;
}
```

Comment: good ideea, but it is possible to make this function to work automaticaly,
Settings array length can have more or less keys.

Comment: Is the last value in the settings array always the deepest level of the search?  And I assume you mean each key could have a different number of values?

Comment: yes, the last value of the settings array is always the deepest array key